# LIKE statement using parametrized SQL in vbscript

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, prepared-statement

I'm trying to create a LIKE SQL statement in vbscript using parametrized SQL.

The command text passed through is along the lines of

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
DECLARE @pname as nvarchar(50); 
SELECT @pname = ?; 
SELECT *
FROM tblProject
WHERE projName LIKE @pname
```

And I'm concatenating % onto either side of the string that I'm passing through as pname. If I change the LIKE to an = and remove the %s then it works fine. And if I run the statement directly and replace *@pname* with *'%searchterm%'* it works fine. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: vbscript:

```
Set rsAnswers = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set cmd = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.CommandText = mySQL
cmd.CommandType = 1
cmd.CommandTimeout = 900 
cmd.ActiveConnection = svrPerformanceConnectionset prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@pname", 129, 1, 50, thisProjName)
cmd.Parameters.Append prm
rsAnswers.CursorLocation = 3
rsAnswers.Open cmd, , 0, 1
```

(thisProjName is getting a string from a form)

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: it should work any special character within `@pname` except `%`

Comment: You should post _all_ the vbscript code. What do you see if you trace it with SQL Profiler?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I've added more vbscript that might be relevant. The whole page is > 1000 lines though and contains confidential info. I hope what I've posted will be enough :) I've taken this code over from somebody else and I'm still very new to vbscript.

Answer (score 0):

it is the expected behaviour because the parameter value is escaped to handle it as a value.

the solution is to move the concatenation of the `%` out of the parameter:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
SELECT *
FROM tblProject
WHERE projName LIKE '%' + @pname + '%';
```

notice the missing declaration & initialization of the parameter: inizialization and value assignement are performed by the VBScript engine and data access layer when creating the related objects in the script.

Comment: Thanks @Paolo. But I still can't quite get it to work. The code that you've given runs fine in the db but not in my asp page. I obviously can't put the 'text to search' part in the query because that is the parameter being passed through. So the command text is like this:

 SET NOCOUNT ON; 
 DECLARE [at]pname as nvarchar(50); 
 SELECT [at]pname = ?; 
 SELECT *
 FROM tblProject
 WHERE projName LIKE '%' + [at]pname + '%';

And then the 'text to search' is being passed through to the ADO object.
 set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("[at]pname", 129, 1, 50, thisProjName)
 cmd.Parameters.Append prm

Comment: please see my edit. since you did not post the vb code at first i supposed the sql was edited to make a test.

Comment: When I remove the declaration from the sql, I get a 'must declare scalar variable' error. Am I not declaring it properly in my vbscript? set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("[at]pname", 129, 1, 50, thisProjName) cmd.Parameters.Append prm

Comment: in your script you have [at]pname or @pname? better add the script to the question...

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this site. I was changing it so it didn't pick it up as a username. I've added the code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things, I found that the problem was the data type I was declaring my parameter as. I'm not sure why exactly but using adVarChar (200) rather than adChar (129) made the LIKE statement work.

Thanks to everybody who answered and commented!